# Vuex/Firestore retrieve user data from another collection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am building a system where users can follow a course. The users can follow a course and this then adds both courseID and userID into a members table. I am failing to then simply list the users information that are following this club (firstName, lastName etc.)

I manage to get the data and console log it but when I commit to my state, the state only shows one of the objects rather than an array which I can loop through.

I have the following collections:

```
Users: -> auto-id -> { firstName, LastName etc. }
Courses: -> auto-id -> { courseName, courseLocation etc. }
Members: -> auto-id -> { courseID, userID etc. }
```

Here is my action within my store:

```
state: {
    members: []
},

mutations: {
    SET_MEMBER_DETAIL(state, val) {
      state.members = val
    },
},

actions: {
    retreiveMembers ({commit}, payload) {
        db.collection('members')
          .where('courseID', '==', payload.courseID)
          .get()
          .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                const documents = doc.data()

                db.collection('users')
                  .doc(documents.userID)
                  .get()
                  .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data())
                    commit('SET_MEMBER_DETAIL', res.data())
                  })
            })
          })
    },
}
```

Here is the result in my console:

```
{admin: false, firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Staron"}

{admin: false, firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Staron"}

{admin: "Admin", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
```

When I view the state via vue chrome add on, I only receive the last array instead of all 3 and as an object.

```
members:    Object
admin:      "Admin"
firstName:  "John"
lastName:   "Doe"
```

I would like to commit the console logged results into my state as an array which i can then loop through on the front end.

Unless there is a more practical way to retrieve relational data with Firestore.

Thanking anyone in advance,
Sam

Comment: Every time you call `commit('SET_MEMBER_DETAIL', res.data())`, you're replacing the previous value of `SET_MEMBER_DETAIL`. You'll want to implement `SET_MEMBER_DETAIL` as an array, and then push each new member to it. See for example the call to `push` in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830731/push-to-vuex-store-array-not-working-in-vuejs

Comment: I did try push, however whenever I loaded another course profile, this held the values of the previous course and duplicated the users to it. I have 3 test users joined to this club, when leaving and returning to that page, I had 6 :/

Comment: So you'll want to commit an empty array to the list whenever you re-run the query. Something like `commit('SET_MEMBER_DETAIL', [])` just before `querySnapshot.forEach`.

Comment: Ok thank you for the feedback, I’ll give that a go. Is there a best/better practice you could recommend for obtaining user related data from different collections? I will likely need to repeat this in order to retrieve related posts/comments etc as I continue to build the app. Thanks :)

Comment: You'll need to either perform additional document loads to get the additional data, or duplicate the data into each member document.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, every time you call `commit('SET_MEMBER_DETAIL', res.data())`, you're replacing the previous value of `SET_MEMBER_DETAIL`. You'll want to implement `SET_MEMBER_DETAIL` as an array, and then push each new member to it. See for example the call to `push` in the answer here: [Push to vuex store array not working in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830731/push-to-vuex-store-array-not-working-in-vuejs).

If `retreiveMembers` may be called multiple times, you'll want to commit an empty array to the list whenever you re-run the query. Something like `commit('SET_MEMBER_DETAIL', [])` just before `querySnapshot.forEach` in your current code.